# MarketingCloudSDK - MobilePush SDK for iOS v8.x - crash

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, sdk

After I managed to fix the original crash “Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model” and now I get the following:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
 reason: 'NSFetchRequest could not locate an NSEntityDescription for entity name 
'SFMCConfigurationEntity''
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: 8.x?  Which version specifically and have you opened a support case?  If not, do that ASAP.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when the [resources bundle](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/tree/spm/Sources/MarketingCloudSDKResources/Resources) called `MarketingCloudSDK.bundle` is not brought into the project. Please ensure you have correctly added the resources bundle inside your project's `Build Phases` section under `Copy Bundle Resources`. This is noted in the docs: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-migration.html